# Validating a model built on multiple regressions

Tags: regression, linear, validation

I have a program that models suspended sediment concentrations (SSC) using turbidity as a predictor and lab derived sediment concentrations as the response.  The relationship between the two can change for a number of reasons but the most significant being large storms vs small storms.  So I use the program to create regressions for each storm then it outputs a continuous time series data set of predicted suspended sediment concentrations.

I generally have 5 separate models for a given water year.  The output looks good if I plot the known lab SSC with the predicted SSC.  But unlike doing a single linear regression for the whole water year and getting the usual model statistics, I have 5 models and the program does not like to output stats of any use.

What would be the best recourse for validating this model?  Calculate everything by hand?  I'm considering using a single model for a given water year just to show the relationship is strong.  Most people use a single model to predict SSC but it is well known separating the storms is considered more accurate which is why I'm using multiple models.

Comment: I have some clarifying questions. A) What software are you using to model the data? B) Are the models manually assigned to different segments of data? C) Is "storm magnitude" a measured quantity of some kind in the modeling? and finally, D) does your software support piecewise models, that is, can all models be combined into a larger model, each selected by some criteria such as date, storm magnitude, etc?

Comment: A)  Aquarius Time-Series software.  We use their rating development toolbox to create the models.  Usually it is meant for stage-discharge relationships but it works just as well for my purposes.  B) They are assigned to different segments of data, say 12/12/16-12/14/16 etc. C) Magnitude is an empirical measurement and is up to the hydrologist to either break up or group a storm.  D)  The models are piece wise based on storm magnitude and time frames and is output as a single time series.